# Getting filename or extension is too long while running grpc using subprocess

Tags: python, windows, curl, subprocess, grpc

Working on grpc. Wrote a code in python using sub process to run grpc from command line. But it is giving error like

```
   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 206]
```

The filename or extension is too long.  for big JSON file. if i send small JSON file it is taking. Couldnt figure out how to overcome it

Code.

```
import subprocess
import json
import os

from pprint import pprint
auth = "authorization: Token asdq"
file = "jsoninput3.json"
fd=open("jsoninput3.json")
json_content = fd.read()
fd.close()
subprocess.run(["grpcurl", "-plaintext","-H", auth,"-d" ,json_content,"-format","json","100.50.10.10:1000","api.Service/MethodName"])
```

Comment: In Windows, a process command line is limited to 32,766 characters. It's not meant for passing large amounts of data. You'll have to find a way to pass the filename or maybe pipe the data to the child's standard input.

Comment: can you share examples or article link if possible it'll help to figure out how to pipe the data

Comment: I've never used grpcurl, so I don't know the option that would make it read data from stdin. On the Python side, you'd simply add the argument `input=json_content`.

Comment: @ is used to open a stdin in grpcurl. But that's giving the same error.